# Flat file info not being displayed when form is re-opened

Tags: php

I am trying to create a simple "notepad" form. I have a pop-up button that when pressed will open a text file (or create one when saved if none exists). The pop up opens, the file gets created/written to. But I can't seem to pull the complete text file back up.

It all works fine until the visitor leaves the page. Meaning they can be on the page, open the file, write to it, save and close. Then, reopen it and all information is there. Add to it if they so choose, and save again. However, When they come back, everything works, except previously saved text doesn't display. It is still in the file, (verified through visual inspection through FTP) but doesn't populate the pop-up.

Still new to learning PHP and am trying to figure it out, but I am quite stuck here.

I haven't tried anything other than making sure POST is done correctly and trying to find similar problems online, but can't locate any.

```
<div id="myNote" class="note">
<div class="note-content">
    <div class="note-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Notepad</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="note-body">
      <p><?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $comment = $_POST['note'] . "\r\n";
            $file = fopen($context['user']['name'] . '.php',"a+");
            fwrite($file,$comment);
            fclose($file); 
            print_r(error_get_last());
        }
      echo '<form action="" method="POST" name="note">
      <textarea name="note" rows="20" cols="40">', $comment, '</textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Note"></form>';
      ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="note-footer">
      <h3>If you close the window without saving, your notes will not be saved.</h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where are you reading the file? It doesn't show in your code.

Comment: string concatenation in php is made of . (dot) and not , (comma). Check around $comment

Comment: @LelioFaieta that's not a string concatenation, it's passing multiple arguments to `echo` and it's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
$comment = $_POST['note'];
```

Populates the textbox

What you want to add is

```
else {
 $comment = fread($context['user']['name'] . '.php', filesize($context['user']['name'] . '.php')); 
}
```

below your if.

should I think do the trick.

Comment: i had to use file_get_contents() instead of fread() but it put me on the right direction. I was forgetting to populate. Your reminder set me straight. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that'll do as well. it's been a while since my php days. FYI. The php extension is probably a hackers dream. You could inject any code into your site. Be careful!

Comment: Yes, I have also added the specialcharacters and slashes removal code lines and a couple of other security measures (files are moved upon saving, no direct access without logging in to an account first, etc. Thanks for the reminder!